# move image without knowing name and overwrite image with php

Tags: php, move, overwrite

I have many images in a folder called A1. Using the following php code I can move a single image from folder A1 to folder A2

```
<?php
rename("/A1/1.jpg", "/A2/1.jpg");
?>
```

The question is how can I move an image without knowing the name of it from the A1 folder to the A2 folder without specifying the file name?(the images in the A1 folder have various names but are all .jpg extension.

Every time the php script is run it should move the next image from the A1 folder to the A2 folder and overwrite the 1.jpg file which was previously moved from A1 folder to A2 folder. (the image must always be renamed to 1.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: If something helped, please accept that answer or add more details otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to move one image at a time?

I'd scan the folder for files and move one file like:

```
$from = '/A1';
$files = scandir($from);

$to = '/A2';
if (!empty($files[2])) {
    rename("{$from}/{$files[2]}", "{$to}/{$files[2]}");
}
```

I used index `2` of `$files` array because there will be always 0 and 1 elements in that array set

```
[0] => .
[1] => ..
```

so if `$files[2]` exist we move it.

If you need to move all files at ones do it in the loop like

```
foreach($files as $file) { /* move */ }
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention the file must always be renamed to 1.jpg when it is moved from A1 to A2

Comment: Then you'll have a collision unless you want to replace the existing 1.jpg file, its easy to change the code and hardcode 1.jpg instead of original file name @John

Comment: yes I need to replace /A2/1.jpg with any of the other images from /A1

Answer (score 2):

That's a simple with [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). Examples:

If you want to move all the files at once:

```
$files = glob('A1/*.jpg');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $filename = basename($file);
    rename($file, "A2/$filename");
}
```

If you want to move them one by one to the target file name 'A2/1.jpg':

```
$files = glob('A1/*.jpg');
if (count($files) > 0) {
    rename($file, 'A2/1.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Ha, we posted almost the same answer at the same time :)

Comment: Thanks I will try that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the finding/listing of files within a directory with the glob function

```
///EXAMPLE
glob('/a1/*.jpg');

//retruns something like the followin array
['test.jpg', 'example.jpg']
```

And then you can simply loop trough the filenames matching the pattern like so:

```
$filesAlreadyMoved= glob('/a2/*.jpg');
$filesFound = glob('/a1/*.jpg');

$filesNotMovedYet = array_diff($filesFound, $filesAlreadyMoved)

foreach ($filesNotMovedYet as $file) {
   //rename is used in the example iven so i will also.
   rename("/A1/1.jpg", "/A2/1.jpg");
}
```

This example will find all files not yet moved and move them.

Comment: Thanks I will try that :)